# array Index out of bound in collection,how?

Tags: java, arraylist, collections

I am working with collection in which I'm trying to reverse a list and getting error as :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 6, Size: 0
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:653)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:429)
    at com.java.commonMethods.CommonClass.rev(CommonClass.java:22)
    at com.java.commonMethods.CommonClass.reverse(CommonClass.java:27)
    at com.java.commonMethods.CallToCommonMethods.callToCount(CallToCommonMethods.java:24)
    at com.java.commonMethods.CallToCommonMethods.main(CallToCommonMethods.java:42)
```

and u can check the code to i'm using to reverse as:

```
public static <E> void rev(List<E> list) {
        List<E> temp = new ArrayList<E>();
        for (int i = 0; i <= list.size(); i++) {
            list.set(i, temp.get(list.size() - i - 1));
        }
    }

    public static void reverse(List<?> list) {
        rev(list);
    }
```

and simply this is the call :

```
List<Integer> listInteger = Arrays.asList(0,1,2,3,4,5);
        CommonClass.rev(listInteger);
        System.out.println(listInteger);
```

can anyone tell me the cause of problem?
and please tell me how is it causing problem and how to fix this issue..
thanks.

Comment: @Tunaki i think you need to check the question and then mark as duplicate if you really know what I'm really trying to ask..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `temp` List is empty, so calling `get` on that List with any index will throw an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` exception.

I'm assuming you intended to initialize `temp` with the elements of the original List.

Therefore, change

```
List<E> temp = new ArrayList<E>();
```

to

```
List<E> temp = new ArrayList<E>(list);
```

As Keppil commented, the range of your loop should also be corrected, since `list.size()` is not a valid index in a `List` of `size()` elements.

Change

```
for (int i = 0; i <= list.size(); i++)
```

to

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
```

Comment: Also `i <= list.size()` should be `i < list.size()`.

Comment: @Keppil Good point. I missed that. Thanks

Comment: thanks @Eran and Keppil